# Text not showing in sidebar in Chrome / Safari

Tags: css, wordpress

Text in the sidebar is not showing on load in Chrome or Safari at [www.signinblue.com/blog](http://www.signinblue.com/blog). Once you inspect the element in Chrome the text shows up. The sidebar displays perfectly in IE7+ and Firefox.

I was previously using Cufon, which I thought was the issue, however, I have removed the Cufon .js and the problem persists.

I have also displayed inline throughout multiple elements to make sure there was nothing hiding the element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify position:

```
#secondary {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 7.6%;
  width: 18.8%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a nesting issue; as the primary div is set to width="100%" it overlaps the secondary div.

Currently the sections are nested as:

```
<div id="primary">
  <div id="content"></div>
</div>
<div id="secondary"></div>
```

Here's the nesting I have used in the Chrome developer tools, this works fine for me:

```
<div id="primary">
  <div id="content"></div>
  <div id="secondary"></div>
</div>
```